# creating trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a table named info_1,with 3 columns those are id,name,and operation.
Now when we insert or update a row, a trigger fires to fill the operation column with the kind of triggering event we are performing, i.e either insert or update.. I am unable to create such a trigger where user only gives information about id,name and operation column fills by itself through trigger. need help.

Comment: Well what have you tried? What are the issues? Where is your code? We have no idea what is preventing you from accomplishing this task.

Comment: Do you mean a stored procedure?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: create or replace trigger_1
before insert on table1
for each row
begin
for(insert)
if:new.operation is null then
insert into table1 (operation) values ( 'insert');
end if;
end for;
end;

Comment: i had used this for insert .. but it isnt working.. its showin Error report:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the operation using a case statement like this:

```
create or replace trigger info_1_tr
before insert or update on info_1
for each row
begin
  :new.operation := case when updating then 'UPDATE' else 'INSERT' end;
end;
/
```